# what is the fault?

Tags: sectioning, errors

I have following section instruction in my text.

```
\section{Properties of $T_{\mathrm{\lowercase{f}}}$; $\mathrm{\lowercase{f}}\overset{4}\equiv{3}$‎ }
```

I get an unintelligible error message when I try to compile this. What is wrong about this?

Comment: I'd bet on `\protect\overset`

Comment: Btw, what's the point of `\lowercase{f}`? f already is a lowercase letter.

Comment: @siracusa in pdf f is presented F, but my symbol is lowercase f.

Comment: Please, add some context, for instance the document class you're using.

Comment: `‎\documentclass[aoas,preprint]{imsart}‎`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three suggestions:

- Prefix the `\overset` instruction, which is "fragile" (in a LaTeX-specific sense of the word), with `\protect`.
- I take it you're using to document class, such as `book`, that provides the section title, rendered in uppercase, in the running header. If that's the case, I suggest you use the optional argument of `\section` to provide the desired look for the running header, and include `\lowercase` instructions as needed.
- Optional: If you prefer to have math material in the section header in bold, provided a `\boldmath` instruction, as is done in the example below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book} % a document class with running header
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\overset" macro
\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{3} % just for this example

\section[Properties of $T_{\mathrm{\lowercase{f}}}$; 
    $\mathrm{\lowercase{f}}\protect\overset{4}{\equiv}3$]%
{Properties of \boldmath$T_{\mathrm{f}}$$\mathrm{f}\protect\overset{4}{\equiv}3$‎‎}

\end{document}
```